# Jquery validate unicode issue

Tags: jquery, unicode, jquery-validate, persian

I using [jquery validation](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation) and jquery v1.9.1.Everything works fine on locall host but when publish website on test server it's not work complete.

If I enter a word like 'hello' or '$#-' another symbol  in a userName on test server  it's work fine, but if  enter  'سلام' (Persian) not work.(in local host 'hello' and 'سلام' work fine)
in rules check active user name,but when type persian word it's not fire and show this error:
'Error Code: 500 Internal Server Error. The request was rejected by the HTTP filter. Contact the server administrator. (12217) 
'

```
 $("#signupForm").validate({
            onkeyup: false,
            rules: {
                username:
                {
                    required: true,
                    remote: {
                        url: "AuthenticateHandler.ashx?type=checkusername",
                        dataFilter: function (data) {
                            if (data == "wrong") {
                                return "\"" + "Username not correct" + "\"";
                            }
                            else if (data == "inactive") {
                                return "\"" + "Username not active" + "\"";
                            }
                            else {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                password: "required",
            },
            messages: {
                username:
                {
                    required: "enter username",
                    remote: "Username not active",
                },
                password: "enter pass",
            },
            submitHandler: function () {
                $.ajax
                    ({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "AuthenticateHandler.ashx?type=checkauthenticate&username=" + encodeURIComponent($("#username").val())
                            + "&password=" + encodeURIComponent($("#password").val()) + "",
                        async: false,
                        data: {},
                        success: function (message) {
```

Comment: [tag:jquery-validation-engine] and [tag:jquery-validate] are two totally different plugins.  Please be more careful when tagging your questions.  Edited. Thanks.

Comment: Your code is chopped off in the middle of the `submitHandler` callback function.

Comment: Pay attention to the last two sentences of the error message:  _"Error Code: 500 Internal Server Error. The request was rejected by the HTTP filter. Contact the server administrator."_

Comment: Is your IIS server maybe running some misguided security filter like URLScan?

Comment: @bobince I don't change default setting of IIS  and i don't use security filter

Comment: @Sparky Thank you for edit my question.I'm confused and have no idea how to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I change publish role settings in ISA following:

Configure HTTP in general tab 
in section 'URL Protection' set uncheck 'block high bit characters'.
[image]